# Display, sort and filter numbers with multiple decimal in excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm using excel 2007.

I've a list of tasks (200-500) that I need to group in different category/section etc (multiple filters). Whole data is in excel table so I can apply Excel's build-in table filters to display exact data that I need.

However it is always difficult to apply multiple filter to display expected data, specially as I need to do it very frequently. To make things simple I'm planning to number each record like

```
a.b.c.d.e.f 

Where a, b, c, d, e, f are simple numbers. List looks like:
1
1.1
1.2
1.2.1
1.2.1.1
1.2.2
1.3
& so on.
```

Problem is, Excel take it as number with single decimal but as soon as I add second decimal, excel treat it as text, which is obvious in general behavior.

However, as special case, I need excel treat both as number or text. Number is preferable as I want to sort them, which might be difficult as a text.

To make the things little more complex, while filtering in table, I require if I can add some formula to filter results like `1.*` should display all numbers starts with `1.`

Is it possible with excel's default behavior, without VBA?

If no, is it possible with VBA? If yes, any clue is appreciated. I don't need whole program as I can write basic VBA program, just a clue how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sort mine by adding a helper column that adds a letter to the front and sort on that. E.g. 1 becomes f1, 1.1 becomes f1.1 etc. Then all are sorted as text.

You can use the formula `="f" & A1`.

My sample:

[image: Sample]

Then the data sorted:

[image: Sorted]

And the filter:

[image: filtered]

Comment: Thanks for reply @glh. That's good idea. We can make all as text. However important question is still there. If we make all of them as text, while filtering in table, it will show all values. How will we add formula in table filter like `1.*`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can filter the column by `f1.*` or `?1.*`

Answer (score 1):

If I were to try this without VBA, my first step would be to use the sort to columns function on the data tab.

[image]

Next make sure all empty spaces in your data are filled with zeros. 
[image]

Then sort the data by column

[image]

as long as you left your original data in the same row as the sorted data (I didn't in the images posted to focus on the process), your items should now be in order.